# Getting error while using the ansible.builtin.shell: module

Tags: linux, ansible, rhel

```
ERROR! this task 'ansible.builtin.shell:' has extra params, which is only allowed in the following modules: set_fact, ansible.builtin.set_fact, ansible.windows.win_shell, ansible.builtin.command, win_command, ansible.legacy.shell, ansible.builtin.raw, ansible.windows.win_command, ansible.legacy.win_shell, ansible.builtin.win_shell, include_vars, add_host, ansible.builtin.include_role, script, command, shell, ansible.legacy.meta, ansible.builtin.import_role, ansible.legacy.include, ansible.builtin.import_tasks, ansible.builtin.add_host, include_tasks, ansible.legacy.raw, ansible.builtin.shell, ansible.legacy.command, ansible.builtin.script, ansible.legacy.include_role, win_shell, ansible.legacy.include_tasks, ansible.legacy.win_command, include_role, ansible.legacy.import_tasks, ansible.builtin.group_by, ansible.legacy.set_fact, ansible.legacy.import_role, group_by, ansible.builtin.win_command, ansible.legacy.group_by, ansible.builtin.include_vars, include, ansible.legacy.script, ansible.builtin.includ…
```

```
- name: Test - Install Package
    ansible.builtin.shell: |
      ./test_uninstall.sh
      ./test_install.sh
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
      chdir: "{{ test_temp_dir }}"
      creates: "{{ test_bin_path }}"
    register: is_test_installed
    until: 
      - is_test_installed.rc is defined
      - is_test_installed.rc|int == 0
```

when i tried running this task i am getting the error mentioned above.. can anyone help on fixing it .

Comment: What does `ansible --version` return on your system?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [This task (name) has extra params, which is only allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66178118/this-task-name-has-extra-params-which-is-only-allowed)

Comment: ansible 2.9 is the version we are using now . and we have 2 .sh script to run ... which was working on the older version of ansible as :                                                                                             - name: Test - Install Package
    shell: |
      ./test_uninstall.sh
      ./test_install.sh
    args:
      executable: /bin/bash
      chdir: "{{ test_temp_dir }}"
      creates: "{{ test_bin_path }}"
    register: is_test_installed
    until: 
      - is_test_installed.rc is defined
      - is_test_installed.rc|int == 0

Comment: Then this question is a duplicate - the linked question has explanation of the reason. In short - there's a bug in that Ansible version. And anyway, it's been released years ago. Consider updating to a maintained version.

Comment: have any other module in ansible can be used alternatively for ansible.builtin.shell module . to run this task ?

Comment: You can use `command` or `raw` (note they all behave differently and it's covered on both documentation and StackOverflow) but your issue is the bug in your Ansible version, not the module you're using.